# SoundTrap 300HF Download Problem

Tags: soundtrap

We have had problems downloading several ST300HFs. Specifically, 7/10 hydrophones have the same problem, one of which was deployed in a different area and uploaded onto a different computer.

- The files are small (all 4mb regardless of recording length)
- Decompressed downloads lack wave files
- Extraction does not create wav files
- It is as if the files are empty

We have tried:

- Resting the hydrophones
- Using a different laptop
- Using Soundtrap Host 3.5 instead of 4
- Updating the firmware

Formatting the memory card and then updating the application firmware has been proposed as an option, but I'd like to try other routes before losing the data. Has anyone had this or a similar problem? Or knows of any possible solutions? A few screenshots for reference. [image]

Comment: This looks very much like wrong setup. To give an answer, more detail is needed. In particular, it would be important to see the log files.

Answer (score 2):

I have had weird things happen when using Soundtrap Host. Something that worked for us is putting the SD cards into hydrophones that were able to offload successfully.

Also check to make sure the default file directory to save downloads is correct as this can cause issues.

You could also try the Soundtrap card reader application and just insert the SD card, although I find this app works worse than Soundtrap Host.